# save file data in mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have a csv file contain 118350 lines,i want to save each line in my database table,i have read entire file in a array and parse every line for some modification and i have started to save file content in my database,i have a php program but the problem is that which save only 927 lines in one time so i have to run my php script again and again to save the further data in database.

my php code is ---

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die(mysql_error($connection));
    $select_db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $connection) or die(mysql_error($connection));

    $file = file('ip-to-country.csv');
    $data = str_replace("\"", "", $file, $j); //for removing ' " ' charactor from string
    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $content = explode(',', $data[$i]);
        $ins = "insert into iplocation (startiprang,endiprang,concode,concode3,country) values ($content[0],$content[1],'$content[2]','$content[3]','$content[4]')";
        $result = mysql_query($ins, $connection);
    }
    echo "done";
?>
```

is there any function which can store all file data in an array without limitation.
myfile size is approx 6 MB. thankx in advance.......i hope you understand what i want... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at load data syntax of mysql. It's much faster and easier. If you post a sample (few rows) of your csv and possibly the output of show create table iplocation, I'll write you the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this csv

http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/6

you can do in this way:

```
create table iplocation (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
startiprang int unsigned,
endiprang int unsigned,
concode varchar(50),
concode3 varchar(50),
country varchar(150)
) engine = myisam;

load data infile 'c:/ip-to-country.csv'
into table iplocation 
fields terminated by ',"'
(@startiprang,@endiprang,@concode,@concode3,@country)
set 
startiprang = replace(@startiprang,'"',''),
endiprang = replace(@endiprang,'"',''),
concode = replace(@concode,'"',''),
concode3 = replace(@concode3,'"',''),
country = replace(@country,'"','')
```

Comment: Didn't you forget about LOCAL keyword?

Comment: I don't know it's contest. He can adapt it easily to his needs. I tested my code before posting it on my own computer. :)

Comment: This will work only if you run mySQL server and client on same machine :]

Comment: I know it. I already wrote that my code must be adapted to his case but I've done 99% of work for the user. Moreover load data local could be even disabled. He can always upload the csv and specify its path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this not a PHP problem. It can be easily solved using [LOAD DATA command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) in mySQL. It'll look like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL '\var\tmp\test.csv' INTO TABLE sometable FIELD TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (column1, column2);
```

But if you really want to solve it with PHP then just create SQL file with INSERT commands in it for each CSV line and execute it with mySQL client.